# Using substring to get a JSON value in PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, json, postgresql, substring

I've got a table field "data" with the following json:

```
[{"reason": "Other", "bla": 12345, "amount": "34.00", "moredata": [23, 22], "date": "2014-01-02T01:55:28.646364+00:00", "message": "Bla", "applied_to": "client"}]
```

And I'd like to get only the value of the json value of amount, so 34.00 in the case above in PostgreSQL.

So far I have:

```
substring(data from '%#"_amount_: ___.___#"%' for '#'),
```

Sadly this gives me "amount":"34.00", instead of just 34.00. It also doesn't work if the amount value is 9.00 or 102.00.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not just use the built-in json support, which has a proper json parser? Or use a PL like plperl and a json lib for it? String-fiddling will be fragile and unreliable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
substring(data from '(?:"amount": ")([\d\.]*)')
```

See it working [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ac770/1) and [here](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%28%3F%3A%22amount%22%3A+%22%29%28%5B%5Cd%5C.%5D%2a%29)'s what it does:

> ```
> NODE                     EXPLANATION
> --------------------------------------------------------------------
>   (?:                      group, but do not capture:
> --------------------------------------------------------------------
>     "amount": "              '"amount": "'
> --------------------------------------------------------------------
>   )                        end of grouping
> --------------------------------------------------------------------
>   (                        group and capture to \1:
> --------------------------------------------------------------------
>     [\d\.]*                  any character of: digits (0-9), '\.' (0
>                              or more times (matching the most amount
>                              possible))
> --------------------------------------------------------------------
>   )                        end of \1
> ```

Comment: Thanks a million for this. I had to make a slight modification in my own case, to use '\w' instead of '\d' for all "word" characters instead of digits only. Also my JSON looked a wee bit different, so I had to remove the space and colon. Here's what mine looked like: "HasOptedOutOfEmail":false     which I parsed using this regex    '(?:"HasOptedOutOfEmail":)([\w\.]*)'